# varation of select statement resultset in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh, cassandra-3.0

I have a large data-set on Cassandra and when i run a query to fetch a limited data-set of 1 or 10 or 100000 on Cassandra it returns rows for first time, but when i try to run the same query again it fetches 0 rows, it works when i exit and login again

Could any one explain me, what is happening?

```
hadmin@cqlsh> use test ;
hadmin@cqlsh:test>  select store_name from data where customers_name = 'LOTTE' limit 1 ALLOW FILTERING;
store_name
---------------------------------
Lottemart
(1 rows)
hadmin@cqlsh:test> select store_name from data where customers_name = 'LOTTE' limit 1 ALLOW FILTERING;
store_name
------------
(0 rows)
```

I'm working on version (3.10)

Comment: How many node in your cluster and what is the replication strategy of your keyspace ?

Comment: Try with CONSISTENCY greater than 1, like QUORUM or ALL

Comment: @AshrafulIslam 2 nodes as of now, but scoped to 2 more servers in near future and i'm following "SimpleStrategy" replication.

Comment: @undefined_variable Okay, I will check that, thanks

Comment: @Naveen Single data center right ?

Comment: @AshrafulIslam Yes, Apologies for late reply